# @blur tag clears value of input in Vue.js SPA compoonent

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am converting an application that uses jQuery to a Vue.js SPA (without jQuery). Currently, some jQuery statements toggle the display of hidden div's when the associated input field has focus, this is then hidden again on blur.

In a vue component I have added a data option of `phoneNumberHasFocus` which is set to true on field focus and false on blur. This works and the display of the div toggles on focus/blur.

However, any value typed into the input field is lost on blur.

```js
export default {
  name: 'profile',
  data: function() {
    return {
      phoneNumberHasFocus: false
    }
  },
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
  <div class="input-area">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" name="phoneNumber" ref="phoneNumber" :value="user.userdetails.phoneNumber" @focus="phoneNumberHasFocus=true" @blur="phoneNumberHasFocus=false" />
  </div>
  <div v-show="phoneNumberHasFocus" class="help-text">
    Please provide a phone number here if you’d like us to contact you by phone when you make an enquiry. Include the area code and extension if required.
  </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone come across this issue before or have an alternative approach to toggling display of the div when the focus is on the input field?

Comment: You might need `v-model` here instead of `:value`

Answer (score 1):

Add `user.userdetails.phoneNumber` to your data method

```
export default {
 name: 'profile',
 data: function() {
  return {
   phoneNumberHasFocus: false
   user: {
     userdetails: {
      phoneNumber: ''
     }
   }
  }
 },
}
```

and use `v-model` for 2 way binding

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="user.userdetails.phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone number" name="phoneNumber" ref="phoneNumber" v-mo="user.userdetails.phoneNumber" @focus="phoneNumberHasFocus=true" @blur="phoneNumberHasFocus=false" />
```

Comment: This was useful in directing me to a solution. I have used the `vuex-map-fields` package, added a computed property via `...mapFields` and updated the html to use the v-model directive. I will post my solution now. I am conscious I did not mentioned the vuex store dependency in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by using the `v-model` directive and `vuex-map-fields` package to provide 2-way data binding to the store, which had the desired outcome of not clearing the field value on blur whilst hiding the related div with the help text.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
  <div class="input-area">
    <input 
      type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number"
      name="phoneNumber" ref="phoneNumber" v-model="phoneNumber"
      @focus="phoneNumberHasFocus=true" @blur="phoneNumberHasFocus=false" />
  </div>
  <div v-show="phoneNumberHasFocus" class="help-text">
      Please provide a phone number here if you’d like us to contact you by phone when you make an enquiry. Include the area code and extension if required.
  </div>
</div>


<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export default {
  name: 'profile',
  data: function () {
    return {
      phoneNumberHasFocus: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapFields([
      'user.userdetails.phoneNumber',
    ]),
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetch_user');
  },
}
</script>
```